# How to get campaign ID from a real time facebook lead?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebooks Webhooks for lead generations. I successfully can fetch leadgen_id from the Facebooks callback.

So this is what Facebook returns for the leadgen field:

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "time": 1583178814,
        "changes": [
          {
            "field": "leadgen",
            "value": {
              "ad_id": "444444444",
              "form_id": "444444444444",
              "leadgen_id": "444444444444",
              "created_time": 1583178812,
              "page_id": "444444444444",
              "adgroup_id": "44444444444"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Is it possible to somehow get campaign ID from these values?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out how to get the campaign id from leadgenId. we can use the Facebook graph leadgen GET API

```
GET /v6.0/<leadgenid>?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&fields=campaign_id'
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

Hope it'll help someone in the future :)